# Graceful labeling of friendship graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I read the Wikipedia page of Friendship Graph which says that it is graceful if and only if its number of cycles is 0 or 1 mod 4.

The right direction is obvious by Rosa, but I cannot seem to construct the labeling. I manage to find it only when the graph has 4 cycles or 8 cycles, but even so I cannot make the general labeling.

I also cannot find the origin paper from Bermond et al. Hence I come here to hopefully get some hints to construct the labeling or maybe a link where I can learn more specifically on the gracefulness of this graph? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's one of the many solutions for $n=5$: $n_0 = 0$, $n_1 = 4$, $n_2 = 6$, $n_3 = 5$, $n_4 = 14$, $n_5 = 8$, $n_6 = 15$, $n_7 = 10$, $n_8 = 13$, $n_9 = 11$, $n_10 = 12$, with $n_0$ the "hub," and $n_{2i+1}$ connected to $n_{2i+2}$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi thanks for the solution.. I can't seem to figure out the pattern tho for the general labeling.. Looks so random.

Comment: It's not so easy.  After imposing some obvious symmetry breaking constraints, there are still 1440 distinct solutions for $n=5$ (and 288 for $n=4$).  The hub vertex is only one $0$, $1$, $3n-1$, or $3n$ in all solutions, but that's the only thing I've spotted.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I see. For $n=8$, I had a hard time already. This paper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph#cite_note-8 seems to have the answer tho, since other papers reference it too, not just wiki..but I cannot find it online..

Comment: I cannot find it online either.  It seems you can always label the hub $0$, and label all the other vertices from $n+1$ to $3n$ in some order that produces the differences from $1$ to $n$ on the "rim" edges.  (The "spokes" obviously get the differences from $n+1$ to $3n$.)  It is not difficult to prove that this method is bound to fail for $n$ congruent to either $2$ or $3$ modulo $4$.  (It's a simple parity argument.)  I don't have a proof that it works in the other cases: only empirical evidence.

Comment: The Bermond, Kotzig and Turgeon paper refers to Thoralf Skolem's *On Certain Distributions of Integers in Pairs with Given Differences*, Math. Scand. 5 (1957), 57-68, which is available online, and contains a construction for the labels of the rim vertices.